# Checking user input against information in a .txt file

Tags: java, file, validation, loops

I am creating a project in which we do a currency exchange. One of the steps is I have to get the user to input what type of currency they want to convert to from a us dollar. I have to do a while loop to check and make sure the input is correct against a text file.

The text file just has this

> CD 1.05 0.93
>   MP 0.11 0.095
>   EU 1.554 1.429

So the person would enter CD MP or EU just not sure how to check it. Using eclipse and the txt file is in the project folder.

```
public class Communication {
    public String askForCode(){

    String currencyCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "We exchange the following Currencies: \n "
            + "CD (Canadian Dollar)\n"
            + "MP (Mexican Peso) \n"
            + "EU (Euro) \n"
            + "Enter the Currency Code"); 

    File myFile = new File("dailyrates.txt");
    while (!currencyCode.equals){

    }
    return currencyCode;

}
```

Would I use the file.next line to validate it?

Comment: so you user will enter `CD 1.05 0.93` and you want to check what currency it is? Read in each line

Comment: Sorry the user only enters the currency code the numbers are the exchange rates. they would only enter CD, MP, or EU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `showOptionDialog`...

[image: Options]

```
    Object[] options = {"CD",
        "MP",
        "EU"};
    int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                    "Enter the FROM Currency Code",
                    "From Currency",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    null,
                    options,
                    options[2]);
```

or even a more restrictive `showInputDialog`...

[image: Option]

```
    Object[] possibilities = {"CD", "MP", "EU"};
    String s = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    null,
                    "Enter the FROM Currency Code",
                    "From Currency",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                    (Icon)null,
                    possibilities,
                    "CD");
```

That would restrict the users available options to what you wanted them to use

See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

You could read the text file, storing the values in an array, `List` or `Map` and use the codes directly within the dialog to add more flexibility...

Answer (score 0):

`Files.readAllLines(Path, Charset)` will read the lines from the file to an ArrayList, which you can change into an array of strings with `toArray()`. You can change your file into a path using `toPath()`. You can then compare the beginning of each line with the string entered until you find the right line.